# How to store month and year in two variable date()?

Tags: php

i would like to extract two variables from the date() function that give me the month and the year, but I don't know how to do it.

I have the next date:

```
$mydate = date('M-Y' , 1705999951);
Output -> Jan-2024
```

From this date, I would like to be able to treat the month and year independently, that is, store them in two variables to be able to perform operations. How can I do it?

Comment: @twofed not work... in example date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2018-12-05 03:05:43'); In my case... date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s', '1705999951');  not work

Comment: You could use `$mydate = (new DateTime)->setTimestamp(1705999951);` to work with  a timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53774962/convert-date-time-string-to-array-php). However, you are using a different format. Here is the modified code for your case:

```
$date = date_create_from_format('U', 1705999951);

$array = [
    (int)$date->format('Y'),
    (int)$date->format('m'),
    (int)$date->format('d'),
    (int)$date->format('H'),
    (int)$date->format('i'),
    (int)$date->format('s')
];

print_r($array);
```

In your example you use Unix timestamp (1705999951), to get date from it you should use 'U' (means Unix) format.

You can use this code to get only two fields:

```
$date = date_create_from_format('U', 1705999951);

$month = $date->format('M');
$year = (int) $date->format('Y');

echo $month;
echo $year;
```

Comment: Thnxx u!! Could u explain me the mean of 'U'? I dont know this format

Comment: @jotade29 I've updated my answer to make it clearer